# How can I print data on pre-printed forms?

Tags: printing, forms

Sometimes we use pre-printed letterhead paper on a regular printer. We can just adjust the margin in Microsoft Word, for instance, and voila...

But this time, I have more than a letterhead paper. It's a pre-printed form that is more complicated that just a letterhead (it was originally designed to be filled in by hand).  I need to print the form content onto the form from a database, and need to use the actual pre-printed forms rather than reproducing it and printing both the form and content.  Here is an example:

[image]

I was wondering if it was possible to use a regular printer to fill in the desired areas of the paper.

Comment: You mean a continuous strip of paper? I don't think so, unless you tore it up manually into separate pages of a size acceptable to the printer.

Comment: @harrymc What I mean is for instance print [this report generated by myself in pdf](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/matrices/tables.png) on my company specific paper. Hence the printing will only consist in filling blank squares

Comment: So I understand this better, let me ask this. You have essentially a form, with blanks for information that you want to run through a standard laser printer so that then that printer could fill in the blanks with information resulting in a completed form? I assume these forms are not three part carbon copy or anything that would require "impact" to complete properly, they are just single page forms that need to be completed?

Comment: @Paperlantern  Yes. You got it right. No carbon. Just single pages needing to be completed through a standard laser printer

Comment: So why not fill out the form electronically using some type of document assembly process like that of HotDocs? Then save it where it needs to be saved for reference and print it out on letterhead or whatever stock is necessary later for filing or mailing etc? What factor is in play here that specifically makes it so that you have to have the PRINTER filling in the data on a hard copy?

Comment: What's a "regular" printer?

Comment: @Paperlantern Data to be filled are coming from a database. The paper is kind of a legal document. It is designed to be filled manually with a pen. But nowaday there are so many entries that we need to populate it via a database. And we do not have (can't afford) a dot matrix printer

Comment: Your comment is rude, and your question unclear.  If by "regular" you mean "laser", then **say so**.  (Some of us are old enough to remember when everyone had dot-matrix printers.  I'm old enough to remember *thermal* printers.

Comment: @RonJohn I guess it was... So sorry comment removed (btw I'm not native english speaker so I must have used an inappropriate expression. sorry again Ron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is just printing specific things in precise locations that will correspond with positions on pre-printed paper (and you say it needs to be on that paper, not a reproduction).  You can do that, but it takes preparation, and the printer needs to be able to register the paper precisely (let's assume that it can).  The task is somewhat similar to creating your own template for printing sheets of labels, except the "labels" can be at random locations on the page, mixed sizes, etc.

There are a few ways to do it.

1. There is software specifically for this purpose (I haven't used any in a very long time, so can't recommend a specific product).  The way it works is you scan the form to produce a template that the software uses.  You identify areas you want to fill in on the template, and the software creates data entry fields.  You typically go through some form of adjustment process to fine-tune the printed location.  Then you use it by viewing an on-screen copy of the form.  You enter the information in the data entry fields.  When you print, it prints only the entered data, and positions it on the pre-printed form.  After setup, the software also typically allows you to simply create a data list that it outputs in the correct place (similar to mailmerge).
2. You can do the above manually.  Measure the exact locations on the paper.  Pick software you know that allows you to position things on a page (word processor, desktop publisher, spreadsheet, etc.).  Create fields, text boxes, cells, or whatever the software uses for units of text, and position them to match the form (may take trial and error for precise alignment).  You need to control and limit the entries to fit on the form within the prescribed areas.

It's hard to provide more specifics based on the question, but that's the gist.  Yes, it can be done, but it can be a lot of work.  It's basically how it was done if you didn't have form-specific software back when computer printers couldn't print high quality output, so you needed preprinted forms like you have.

Comment: You've totally understood what I meant. I heard of the second solution from a co-worker. Can I the software in the first answer ? Also, can I, if you have time or a resource, explanation on how to implement the second solution ? Anyways thank you. The name of the software of 1st solution will be a starting point for me. Thx ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much... I'm not native speaker so added to your answer, I needed the expression `pre printed form`. it led me to [this Adobe Pro youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ACV1remiUI). Thanks Fixer. It you have another free software, let me know of it please

Comment: @snorlax, the last time I used this kind of software was probably in the 1980s or 1990s when it was still a common requirement.  I also did it manually a few times with a word processor (a royal pain in the butt).  "preprinted form" is probably a good search term.  Also "form filler" comes to mind.  Back when I needed it, I forget whether Adobe offered that feature (or maybe I didn't want to pay for the Pro version if it did), but it looks like a good solution.  (cont'd)

Comment: Also, look at your word processor form features.  It might have the tools to facilitate this (e.g., print text boxes only, or hide all the other content when printing).

Answer (score 1):

If the reason for this problem is that you need to use a form that is only found on
this old paper, you could scan it and use as background image in a document,
then print on normal paper while filling in the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using continuous feed paper with perforations on both sides of the page, you can't, unless you want to do a lot of work.  You would have to separate each page of the continuous feed and remove the perforations from both sides of the paper.

Comment: What I mean is for instance print [this report generated by myself in pdf](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/matrices/tables.png) on my company specific paper. Hence the printing will only consist in filling blank squares